# X over SSH error

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, ssh, xorg

So I have a simple question. I am trying to run programs that use graphics rendering using X11 forwarding. Currently I have two computers both running XUbuntu 16.04 LTS, a desktop and a laptop. I am connecting via ssh on the laptop as follows

```
ssh -X user@ip
```

Then I try to run a program called `Gputest` and I get this error

```
./GpuTest 

ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target
   specification), specified in query 'NvidiaDriverVersion'.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Both computers have NVIDIA graphics cards and both are running on the same driver version (340.96). I have also tried using different variations of drivers all give the same result. I can however run programs like `libreoffice` just fine using X over SSH.  Is there something I am missing, or is X11 forwarding not capable of displaying these types of '3D programs'?

Comment: Hmm...  Maybe a simple question, but not necessarily a simple answer!  :)  Have you tried `./GpuTest` on both computers?

Comment: Just as a wild idea, are you using a CRT by any chance?

Comment: And another question, are you 100% positive that you are actually using the NVIDIA drivers?  `nvidia-settings -q screens`

Comment: Yes ./Gputest works on both computers locally.  I am using an lcd monitor and yes the problem only occurs when I switch from nouveau drivers to nvidia drivers.  Gputest works with nouveau

Comment: I know I am returning topic from dead (maybe) but have you solved this issue?